# Jupyter Notebook/Firefox hangs when dealing with a bit of resource intensive script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, crash, freeze

When I use Jupyter Notebook in linux firefox on very light applications I have no problems. As I increase a bit the application resource intensivity, the browser tab becomes unresponsive or so and takes a lot of time to accomplish the task,or worse, it crashes the pc completely. By instance in the script I am working on, I am reading a dataframe from a 1.5 Mb Pickle file, and then perform some elaboration operations on that data by putting in lists. That's around a 3500 rows dataframe and I take only part of that to elaborate. The time() function tells me that the program takes around 9 seconds to complete. However it actually takes many minutes.
I have 16Gb Ram quad core and dynamic swap. The ram usage doesn't appear to be high in my monitoring tool. I think it's a jupyter/Firefox problem. Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only on Windows10. I followed the instructions here - https://medium.com/@vusal.kamalzada/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-to-chrome-in-windows-cf348dd5ed40 and now working on Chrome (unfortunately) but it seems to work better at the moment

Comment: @user88484 thanks, I actually don't remember if I resolved that issue. I surely implemented some memory cleaning function. However at one point I discarded jupyter notebook and passed to pycharm, which is more consonant to my programming workflow. Thank you for reporting.